# Spark-java 2.5 & Pebble - always Internal Server Error

Tags: spark-java, pebble

When I follow the tutorial for using Pebble with Spark-Java framework 2.5, I just get an Internal Server Error with no stack crawl.

I can get Freemarker working, and Velocity as well - but not Pebble which is of course the one I want to use.

I tried joining the google group for spark java two days ago and still waiting for admission which seems a tad slow tbh.

I've tried placing the template in resources, resources/public, resources/public/spark - nothing seems to work.

Has anyone managed to make this work?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the default DelegatingLoader for PebbleEngine, it sounds like you're not passing a valid path to ModelAndView. If you place your template in your root directory, and pass the path "./my-template.pebble" to the ModelAndView constructor, it should work.

Edit: I've merged an update for the example spark-template-pebble project, you can view it [here](https://github.com/perwendel/spark-template-engines/tree/master/spark-template-pebble).

Comment: What would the "root" directory be in this case?

Comment: @celestialorb The root directory is the topmost directory in your project hierarchy. Most usually the directory with your pom.xml, I think.